# How do we add an image that's not from google?

Tags: html, css

How do we add an image that's not from google? It's a picture I took myself on my mobile phone and emailed it to my computer.

Comment: this person is  very smart. i like her

Comment: who  minus my question??????

Comment: this  is a serious mattter

Comment: can someone please answer me

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take a moment to re-read the guidelines for asking questions here in the [Help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help).
The Q&A format of Stack Overflow does not lend itself this sort of question. Questions such as this don't really work with objective answers. If you are looking for tutorials on how to do something such as this best bet is to do a Google search, and if you have a specific question such as you have tried something and it isn't working then that would be a more appropriate question for this sort of format.

Answer (score 0):

When making a website. Just put all your files in 1 folder. You can have subfolders. When wanting to link an image just put it somewhere in that folder and then just use the path to it.

Answer (score -1):

One of the site's rules is:

`Don't ask about questions you haven't tried to find an answer for (show your work!).`

I guess this is the reason why you got those minuses.

Read here: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_images.asp about how to add images to HTML code.

A solution for your problem could be:

- `<img src="myimage.jpg">`, if we add images from HTML code.
- `background-image: url(myimagee.jpg);`, if we add images from CSS code.

Answer (score -1):

So you need to do is provide a source for the pictures to display.
you would do

Just make sure to reference where the picture is comming from, if its in the same location as your html this will work. If its in a folder then you need to specify

here is a good reference, W3 Schools will help you alot here
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_images.asp